# How can I silence ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, output

I have a script like this one at my `.bashrc` file at the `mysuer` home:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add /path/to/my/key
```

The problem is I have this output when I log with the user `mysuer` (`su - myuser`):

```
Agent pid 1234
Identity added: /path/to/my/key (/path/to/my/key)
```

I would like avoid this, silence this output, but load the `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`.

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As usual?

```
{ eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add /path/to/my/key; } &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `-q` flag to silence successful operations. Ex: `ssh-add -q /path/to/my/key`

[Source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-add.1.html)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please be sure to state its prerequisites - on my installation, that command results in `unknown option -- q`.